# SQL Query - Multiple Table Join With Grouping Functions that Keep Branch Structure

Tags: sql-server, join, report, branch, aggregation

I have exhausted my search for a solution and would like to post my question to see if a solution exists.

I need to write a report to show the debits and credits per branch.  The report needs also show if branches have had no DBs or CRs.

For simplicity I have scaled down my tables to try highlight my issue.

My first table holds my Branch Data

```
BranchNo    BranchName
1           Main
2           Mgorogoro
3           Arusha
```

My second table holds all Debit Transactions

```
txid    Narrative   Amount  Date        BranchNo
1       Test 1      50.00   2014/11/26  1
2       Test 2      20.00   2014/11/27  3
```

I've written a SQL statement that gives me the results I need:-

```
DECLARE @get_Dates CURSOR;
DECLARE @Date VarChar(10);

DECLARE @tbl TABLE
                (
                    DebitOutCount int, 
                    BranchCode VarChar(250),
                    TxDate VarChar(10)
                )
--DECLARE @tbl TABLE(Idx1 VarChar(50), Idx8 VarChar(50), Idx3 VarChar(50))

SET @get_Dates = CURSOR FOR 
    Select Debits_OUT.Date FROM Debits_OUT GROUP BY Debits_OUT.Date ORDER BY Debits_OUT.Date

OPEN @get_Dates;

FETCH NEXT FROM @get_Dates into @Date;

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)

    BEGIN 
        --INSERT INTO @tbl SELECT Idx1, Idx8, Idx3 FROM SessionDailyControl WHERE Idx1 = @sessionId
        INSERT INTO @tbl 
            SELECT 
            (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(DB_OUT.Amount), 0) FROM Debits_OUT AS DB_OUT WHERE B.BranchNo = DB_OUT.BranchNo AND DB_OUT.Date = @Date) AS DebitOutValue,
            CAST(B.BranchNo As VarChar(10)) + ' ' + B.BranchName As [Branch Names],
            @Date
            From exBranches As B

        FETCH NEXT FROM @get_Dates into @Date
    END 

CLOSE @get_Dates

DEALLOCATE @get_Dates

SELECT * FROM @tbl
```

The result is in the format that I need:-

```
DebitOutCount   BranchCode  TxDate
50              1 Main      2014/11/26
0               2 Mgorogoro 2014/11/26
0               3 Arusha    2014/11/26
0               1 Main      2014/11/27
0               2 Mgorogoro 2014/11/27
20              3 Arusha    2014/11/27
```

However, the report tools and Views cannot work with the above.  I have tried Left Joins - but the problem is the result set will not keep the branch numbers for dates where there were zero transactions.  For Example:-

```
SELECT 
    ISNULL(SUM(B.Amount), 0),
    CAST(A.BranchNo As VarChar(10)) + ' ' + A.BranchName As [Branch Names],
    B.Date 
From exBranches As A
    LEFT JOIN Debits_OUT AS B ON A.BranchNo = B.BranchNo
GROUP BY B.Date, A.BranchNo, A.BranchName 
ORDER BY B.Date, A.BranchNo, A.BranchName
```

Returns:-

```
DB_OUT  Branch Names    Date
0.00    2 Mgorogoro     NULL
50.00   1 Main          2014/11/26
20.00   3 Arusha        2014/11/27
```

In all the JOIN combinations that I try, I cannot get the branches to show ALL the branches for each date that is in the debits table.

Is there a fundamental concept that I have completely missed?  I need have a query that can be run in a view that returns the same data as the cursor statement.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to generate possible combinations of Branches and dates first:

```
create table exBranches(
    BranchNo int,
    BranchName varchar(20)
)
create table Debits_OUT(
    txId int,
    Narrative varchar(20),
    Amount decimal (6,2),
    [Date] date,
    BranchNo int
)
insert into exBranches values (1, 'Main'), (2, 'Mgorogoro'), (3, 'Arusha')
insert into Debits_OUT values (1, 'Test 1', 50.00, '20141126', 1), (2, 'Test 2', 20.00, '20141127', 3);

with BranchDate as(
    select
        b.BranchNo,
        b.BranchName,
        d.Date
    from exBranches b
    cross join (
        select distinct [Date] from Debits_OUT
    )d
)
    select
        isnull(DebitOutCount,0),
        cast(b.BranchNo as varchar(10)) + ' ' + b.BranchName as BranchName,
        b.Date
    from BranchDate b
    left join (
        select
            branchNo,
            [Date],
            sum(Amount) as DebitOutCount
        from Debits_OUT
        group by
            BranchNo, [Date]
    )d 
        on d.BranchNo = b.BranchNo
        and d.Date = b.Date
order by b.date, b.BranchNo asc

drop table exBranches
drop table Debits_OUT
```

Comment: Brilliant!! - that's taken to a whole new level of SQL Joins.  Thank you.  I would vote up - but don't have the points yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try This it's works.....

```
  select BranchName,amount,date1,BranchNo into #temp from exBranches 
  cross join (select distinct date1,amount from Debits_OUT)a

  select isnull(t.amount,0),a.BranchName,a.date1  from #temp a
  left join Debits_OUT t on t.BNo=a.BranchNo and a.date1=t.date1
  order by date1
```

view here.. 
  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ad815/1

Comment: I completely agree - it returns the correct results.  Unfortunately I couldn't save the query as a view due to some of the functions used, which makes me doubt it would work in a report.  I will however try it as a raw sql data source in the report wrtier I'm using and let you know the results.  Many thanks.